# Couldn't match expected type in Haskell during pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have copied this chunk of code 1:1 from "Practical Haskell: A Real World Guide to Programming" from
Alejandro Serrano Mena but for some reason it doesn't take input properly.

```
module Chapter2.Datatypes2 where

    data Person = Person String String Gender
                deriving Show
    data Gender = Male | Female | Unknown
                deriving Show

    data Client = GovOrg     String
                | Company    String Integer Person String
                | Individual Person Bool
                deriving Show

    clientName :: Client -> String
    clientName client = case client of
                          GovOrg  name                -> name
                          Company name _ _ _ -> name
                          Individual person ads       ->
                              case person of
                                Person fNm lNm gender -> fNm ++ " " ++ lNm
```

Compiling goes fine but when I feed the function with `(Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False`, it get the following errors from the interpreter:

```
<interactive>:27:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Bool -> t'
                  with actual type `[Char]'
    * The function `clientName' is applied to two arguments,
      but its type `Client -> [Char]' has only one
      In the expression:
        clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False
      In an equation for `it':
          it = clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:27:1)

<interactive>:27:13: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Client'
                  with actual type `Bool -> Client'
    * Probable cause: `Individual' is applied to too few arguments
      In the first argument of `clientName', namely
        `(Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male])'
      In the expression:
        clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False
      In an equation for `it':
          it = clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False

<interactive>:27:24: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Person' with actual type `[Person]'
    * In the first argument of `Individual', namely
        `[Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]'
      In the first argument of `clientName', namely
        `(Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male])'
      In the expression:
        clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clientName (Individual (Person "Jack" "Smith" Male) False)
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you mind giving an explanation? Haskell is known for functions that don't require parentheses and this feels like a violation.

Comment: @Saten-san: Parentheses are only required for *grouping*. `clientName (Individual [Person "Jack" "Smith" Male]) False` calls `clientName` with two arguments, `Individual […]` (of type `Bool -> Individual`) and `False` (of type `Bool`), which is an error because `clientName` only takes one argument. `Individual` also takes a single `Person` as its first argument, not a list `[Person]`. This is like writing `print length "ABC"` when you want `print (length "ABC")` or `print $ length "ABC"`. `clientName (Individual (…) False)` passes one argument to `clientName` and two arguments to `Individual`.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're amazing!